# Render view with anchor tag in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do you render a page, but with the anchor tag as well in express.js routes?

So: `website.com/route#id-of-html-element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like if you code your hyperlink in the usual way and add the anchor `<a href="/route#anchor1">link</a>`, then add the anchor id/name on the desired destination page `<a id="anchor1" name="anchor1"></a>`, express will simply carry the `#anchor1` over to the routed page and the client will then jump to where the anchor is. Nothing special in the routes code is required. This seems to work fine using res.render in my test.

```
router.get('/route', (req, res, next) => { 
    res.render('route')
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The anchor tag is not sent between client and server. Only the client deals with it. I think the only way to do this would be something like this:

```
res.render ('view', {anchor: 'anchor'});
```

in Express, then in your template put some javascript:

```
if anchor
    script.
        window.onload = window.location.hash = '#{anchor}';
```

Comment: This is a smart solution, but one thing is after the redirect, I lose all the other render variables. For example if you send "title" in res.render, after it redirects to the hash, the title will be blank. Any workaround for this?